# How can I resolve this problem 'Cannot read property 'style' of null at HTMLBodyElement'?

Tags: javascript, null, styles

I've a navigation menu which dissappears when the breakpoint is 400px and icon bars appear. I added an eventListener and when I click on the icon I've my message in the console, but when I added if statements I've got an error message 'Cannot read property 'style' of null at HTMLBodyElement'.
I've already read similar questions but still I can't resolve the problem.

```
    .cont-menu-a{
        margin-top: 10%;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-right: 10%;
        margin-bottom: 35%;
        height: 62%;
        @media only screen and (max-width: $sm) {
          display : none;
        }
     }
      .fa-grip-lines{
        color: #212529;
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin-left: 5%;
        margin-top: 5%;
      @media only screen and (min-width: $sm) {  
        display : none;
     }}

`<div class="about-page">
    <div class="sous-menu-burger">
        <i class="fas fa-grip-lines"></i>
    </div> 
  

      <div class="cont-main">
            <div class="cont-menu-a"> 
                <a href="#"><div class="home-a">Home</div></a>
                <a href="#"><div class="about-a">About</div></a>
                <a href="#"><div class="skills-a">Skills</div></a>
                <a href="#"><div class="projects-a">Projects</div></a>
                <a href="#"><div class="contacts-a">Contacts</div></a>
            </div>

    <div class="cont-text">
        <div class="titre">About</div>
        <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A repellat natus praesentium ratione ullam ipsa, perspiciatis consectetur, optio excepturi id cum maxime recusandae corrupti nihil. Illo deleniti eaque quod enim.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil laudantium optio ex nobis. Voluptatibus optio inventore doloremque. Perspiciatis temporibus ipsa quisquam expedita officiis? Nulla quod perferendis maiores repudiandae, vero eaque!
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis earum a impedit, laborum magni fugit molestias, modi possimus quod hic consequuntur ad rem sed. Repudiandae, cupiditate perspiciatis! Pariatur, quia voluptatem.
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`;


    const contSousmenu = document.querySelector('.cont-menu-a');
    
    document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      if (e.target.matches('.fa-grip-lines')) {
        console.log('toto'); 
        if (contSousmenu.style.display === 'none') {
          contSousmenu.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          contSousmenu.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Your code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="about-page">
      <div class="sous-menu-burger">
        <i class="fas fa-grip-lines"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="cont-main">
        <div class="cont-menu-a">
          <a href="#"><div class="home-a">Home</div></a>
          <a href="#"><div class="about-a">About</div></a>
          <a href="#"><div class="skills-a">Skills</div></a>
          <a href="#"><div class="projects-a">Projects</div></a>
          <a href="#"><div class="contacts-a">Contacts</div></a>
        </div>

        <div class="cont-text">
          <div class="titre">About</div>
          <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A repellat
            natus praesentium ratione ullam ipsa, perspiciatis consectetur,
            optio excepturi id cum maxime recusandae corrupti nihil. Illo
            deleniti eaque quod enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
            adipisicing elit. Nihil laudantium optio ex nobis. Voluptatibus
            optio inventore doloremque. Perspiciatis temporibus ipsa quisquam
            expedita officiis? Nulla quod perferendis maiores repudiandae, vero
            eaque! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Perspiciatis earum a impedit, laborum magni fugit molestias, modi
            possimus quod hic consequuntur ad rem sed. Repudiandae, cupiditate
            perspiciatis! Pariatur, quia voluptatem.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      const hamburger = document.querySelector(".fa-grip-lines");
      const contSousmenu = document.querySelector(".cont-menu-a");

      hamburger.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        console.log("toto");
        if (contSousmenu.style.display === "none") {
          contSousmenu.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          contSousmenu.style.display = "none";
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I have a script.js file with listeners and another file in which I put this html. I made export and import, so it worked but with addEventListener it doesn't work. Maybye the page doesn't exist or wasn't loaded before my eventListener?